# Прокрутка скроллом на высоту блоков

Tags: javascript, jquery, прокрутка, веб-дизайн

Как сделать чтобы при скролле прокрутка страницы происходила ровно на высоту блоков, которые в ней находятся (код внутри)?

Не хочу использовать библиотеки, потому что, наверняка, нужно дописать 2-5 строк кода, чтобы решить вопрос с прокруткой страницы при скролле на высоту блока (на заданное количество пикселей).

**И второй вопрос**, как сделать эту прокрутку плавной, чтобы не было ощущения, что просто переключили блок с одного на другой.

```js
function slide() {
  h = document.documentElement.clientHeight
  $(".one, .two, .three").css('height', h);
};

$(window).resize(slide);
$(document).ready(slide);
```

```css
.one,
.two,
.two {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.one {
  background: #CD5;
}
.two {
  background: aquamarine;
}
.three {
  background: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one"></div>
<div class="two"></div>
<div class="three"></div>
```

Comment: нашел что то наподобие, только при большом скролле плохо работает https://jsfiddle.net/v7ok83oa/2/

Comment: магических строк там явно не несколько, плавность вроде css трансформациями достигается, посмотрел внутрь http://luke.sno.wden.co.uk/full-screen-vertical-scroll

Comment: добавил ответ))

Comment: http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-snappoints - ждём :)

Comment: @Qwertiy в хроме пашет.

Comment: во всех моих пашет) пойдет ладно у кого не пашет, тому и не надо это видеть))

Comment: @Jean-Claude, в какой версии? У меня не работает.

Comment: @Qwertiy, 48.0.2564.116 m

Comment: @Qwertiy 48.0.25 и только что обновился 49 пашет. А че, scrolltop через snappoints реализован?

Comment: @Jean-Claude, а при чём тут scrolltop?

Comment: @Qwertiy а при чем тут тогда snappoints?

Comment: Что тут вообще происходит??

Answer (score 3):

Эврика!

```js
function slide() {
  h = document.documentElement.clientHeight
  $(".one, .two, .three").css('height', h);
};
$(window).resize(slide);
$(document).ready(slide);


$(document).bind('mousewheel DOMMouseScroll', function(event) {
  scroll(event);
});

var num = 1;
var scrolling = false;

function scroll(event) {
  event.preventDefault();
  if (!scrolling) {
    scrolling = true;
    if (event.originalEvent.wheelDelta > 0 || event.originalEvent.detail < 0) {
      num--;
      num = num < 1 ? 1 : num;
    } else {
      num++;
      num = num > 3 ? 3 : num;
    }

    $('html, body').animate({
      scrollTop: $(".num" + num).offset().top
    }, 500, "linear", function() {
      scrolling = false;
    });
  }
}
```

```css
.one,
.two,
.two {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
}
.one {
  background: #CD5;
}
.two {
  background: aquamarine;
}
.three {
  background: #2196F3;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="one num1"></div>
<div class="two num2"></div>
<div class="three num3"></div>
```